# Spring cloud server do not read from local filesystem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

Getting below Json response for the url http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default. It is not reading the file `limit-service.properties`.

```json
{
    "name": "limits-service",
    "profiles": ["maximum"],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": []
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name = spring-cloud-confg-server
server.port = 8888
spring.profiles.active = native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations = file:///C:/Learning/configs-repo/
```

**limit-service.properties (path C:/Learning/configs-repo/)**

```
limits-service.maximum = 8999
limits-service.minimum = 8
```

**SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.java**

```java
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Could you please help me understanding why it is not reading the file ?

Comment: What is the error message you get int the application log?

Comment: o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment         : Activating profiles [default]
 o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Not adding property source: file [C:\Learning\configs-repo\limits-service.properties
m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json]
m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [Environment [name=limits-service, profiles=[default], label=null, propertySources=[], version=null,  (truncated)...]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK

Comment: You tried something like limits-service-maximum.properties and rename the proeprties to not contain the profile?

Comment: No It is not reading the message from the property.Whatever may be the message inside it

Answer (score 1):

it was not working with Spring boot 2.4.1 and Spring Cloud config server 2020.0.0-M6. Wheres when I changed to Spring boot 2.3.7.RELEASE and Spring cloud config server Hoxton.SR9 it is working