# Spring cloud config server is reading properties from source repo is empty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, configserver

Output when I try to check the values present in the repo properties by accessing the spring cloud config server

```
http://localhost:8888/foo/default
```

By accessing the above url

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": "null",
  "version": "null",
  "state": "null",
  "propertySources": []
}
```

Similar question is in

[Spring cloud server not able to read from loacl File system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65300932/spring-cloud-server-not-able-to-read-from-loacl-file-system)

and

[Using Spring Cloud Config without Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178448/using-spring-cloud-config-without-git-repo)

But both did not help tried that,

**MY IMPLEMENTATION IS AS FOLLOWS**

Spring Cloud Config Server Application Properties:

```
    server.port=8888
    spring.application.name=server_app
    spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///C:/Users/rmks/git/repo
    spring.profiles.active=native
```

Spring Cloud Config Client Application Properties :

```
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=client_app
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

Actual properties file values in the local git repo is :

```
foo.name = xyz, 
foo.gender = F
```

The git repo location is

> file:///C:/Users/rmks/git/repo

under repo folder have the below structure

> .git

> .project

> foo.properties

**Tried with below version combinations:**

> Spring boot parent : 2.3.7.RELEASE  & Spring cloud dependency: Hoxton.SR9
>
> Spring boot parent : 2.3.2.RELEASE & Spring cloud dependency: Hoxton.SR8
>
> Spring boot parent : 2.5.4 & Spring cloud dependency: 2020.0.4

*Not sure if the issue is due to the version of boot and cloud. Based on the first stack overflow link I tried with different version. Confused what is the root cause or is there any issue with my config server implementation.*

Other dependency added in boot are :

> spring.cloud.config.server

Comment: Any logs you can provide? can you provide a sample project? There's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Please, try to remove `spring.profiles.active=native`

Comment: Did you get this to work in the end?